# Excel se crashea al corer un codigo llamado desde otra userform

Tags: excel, vba

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente código en una UserForm en VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim tblu As ListObject
Dim wsu As Worksheet
Dim newRowu As ListRow

If Me.TextBox1.Text = "" Or Me.TextBox2.Text = "" Or Me.TextBox3.Text = "" Then
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("B2").Value = 0 Then
    
        MsgBox "All fields are required.", vbCritical
    
    End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B2").Value = 1 Then
        
        MsgBox "Todos los campos son requeridos.", vbCritical
    
    End If

End If


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Users").visible = True

Set wsu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Users")
Set tblu = wsu.ListObjects("Table2")
Set newRowu = tblu.ListRows.Add


newRowu.Range(1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
newRowu.Range(2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
newRowu.Range(3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Text

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Users").visible = xlVeryHidden

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B2").Value = 1 Then
     MsgBox "Datos guardados correctamente."
End If

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B2").Value = 0 Then
     MsgBox "Data saved successfully"
End If

ThisWorkbook.Save
 
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Si lo ejecuto desde la misma UserForm, todo bien.
El problema viene cuando yo llamo a esta UserForm desde otra, a la hora de ejecuar este código me aparece el mensaje: Method "Add" of object "ListRows" failed
Después de eso, Excel deja de funconar y se cierra.

¿Hay algún error en el código o alguna limitación que esté pasando por alto?

Comment: Crea un [punto de interrupción](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/stop-statement) al principio de tu código, reproduce el error y entonces ejecuta el código paso a paso con F8. Así podrás ver el momento exacto en el que falla y ponerle solución.